# Should I jump rope even though I suffer from flat feet?

Tags: bodybuilding, cardio, bodyweight-exercises, feet, jump-rope

I have flat feet. I don't think it's that severe though. It was my leg day a couple of days back and I did squats, lunges, exntensions, curls and some rope jumps. However, today, my left knee hurts. It's cardio day today. I feel running or jogging would make matters worse so I plan on sticking to the elliptical trainer. However, I feel jumping rope is an excellent exercise. This is why I wanted to ask you all whether it is advisable to do it given my condition or would I be better off not doing it at all. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do some research on [flat feet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_feet), and I think you'll see that it's not really anything to concern yourself with. I have rather flat feet myself, and have never noticed a problem except when others tell me I should deal with my flat feet.

In fact, if you start looking into [the research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16130646) a bit, you won't find any smoking guns that indicate being flat footed, but you may see some that say very high arches are a problem.

> This study provides high-level evidence that foot shape has little
>   impact on pain, injury, and functioning among military recruits.

So, jump rope away. If you want to strengthen your feet, go ahead and (seriously) take some walks on the beach to strengthen your arches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i think that you can definitely do it.
But what you need to use is some good shoes for it. The kind that makes your heels pretty up from the floor. Good for your feet and your back too.
Do not opt for converse/vans style for this kind of exercice.

If you feel that your knees hurt and that they're showing signs of fatigue, better give them some rest for the remaining of this week.
have a nice day & a Good jumping ;)