# Flat feet causing knees to point in

Tags: knees, feet

Since I can remember, my knees have pointed inward when bending at the knees. If I stand with my feet an inch or two apart, facing forward, and start bending my knees, they quickly knock into each other. From what I've read online, this is called knee valgus and has a number of causes, such as poor ankle dorsiflexion, weak hip adductors, tight calves, and tight abductors. I've tried various things to improve in each of these areas, though nothing has had an affect on the angles my knees point inward.

I've recently started to suspect that this is because I am flat footed. When I rotate my foot outward so that I'm standing on the outside of the foot, my knees point forward normally. I believe the problem is that my collapsed arches are causing my ankle to be rotated inward, which is in turn causing my knees to follow.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: This isn't on topic here; it's more about medical conditions. Regarding flat feet though, maybe read this: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/28763/7091

Comment: Are you asking for exercises?

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see why the base of the foot being flat should cause the leg to tip over, rather than being a normal leg that just has more of the sole of the foot on the ground. If your hip, knee, and ankle are misaligned like the following image, then I think you should work on the knee valgus. Use [Bret Contreras' diagnostic tests](http://bretcontreras.com/knee-valgus-valgus-collapse-glute-medius-strengthening-band-hip-abduction-exercises-and-ankle-dorsiflexion-drills/) to see whether your valgus is caused by ankle mobility, hip mobility, or lack of coordination.[image]